# Modificar el año del "Filter by Data Range" en DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Lo que deseo es poder modificar a mi antojo el año que se muestra en el SELECT del año, en este "datepicker" (Filter by Data Range) de un DataTable.

Acá dejo la fuente de referencia:
https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No deseo modificar el rango, si no mas bien setear un año en específico.

Gracias de antemano,

Saludos.

Comment: Saludos. Los `datepicker` no son parte del `DataTable`; solo agrega uno que solo te permita números (para evitar errores). Con el valor `var date = new Date( data[4] );` comparar el contenido del año que especificas respecto al año de la variable`date`.

Comment: Qué sería: `data[4]` ?

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. `data[4]` representa (del `DataTable`) la columna numero 5 (de la primera su índice es 0) que es el **Start date**.

Comment: Cómo sería en un ejemplo?

Comment: En base a mi sugerencia. Dentro del `function( settings, data, dataIndex )` el `if` seria compara el año que pones respecto al de la columna `(date.getFullYear()=="aqui la variable que contenga el año")`; claro, tienes que considerar el escenario que el año no lo proporcionen, que sea un número válido.

Comment: Y usando el dateTime JS, cómo debería hacer?

Comment: Es necesario el código que tienes implementado en tu proyecto o página para darte sugerencias de cambios con los nombres de los elemento y lo que tienes en JS para los cambios que aplicarian.